# How to pass/send the number of selected row in UITableViewController to another class?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, xcode4.5

Dudes, i'm having some trouble here in XCODE4.5 and I hope you can help me!

How can I pass or send the integer value of the selected row in UITableViewController to another ViewController, using the method  didSelectRowAtIndexPath?

Here is my code :

```
SecondViewController.h
{
NSInteger myInteger;
}
@property(nonatomic) NSInteger myInteger;

SecondViewControl.m
-(void)viewDidLoad {
NSLog(@" the number is = %d",myInteger); //this is not working, I always get "the number is = 0 "
}


FirstViewController.h
#import "SecondViewController"
//...

FirstViewController.m
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath  *)indexPath {
if (indexPath) {
 NSIndexPath *path = indexPath;
    NSInteger theInteger = path.row;
 NSLog(@"selected row = %d", theInteger); //code OK

//THE PROBLEM STARTS HERE!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!   

SecondViewController *second = [[SecondViewController alloc]init];
    [second setMyInteger:theInteger];
// i'm trying to use "second.myInteger = theInteger;" , but it's also not working

}
}
```

Thank you guys!

Comment: One. The IDE is not called 'XCODE', nor 'xCode', 'XCode' or anything else - its proper name is 'Xcode'. Two, anyway, this has nothing to do with Xcode. You can write iOS apps using command line tools like nano and make with the appropriate cross-toolchain - you should probably retag your question to include the 'cocoa-touch' tag instead of the Xcode one.

Comment: Does the class `SecondViewController` declare a property `myInteger` or implement a method `setMyInteger:`?

Comment: @NSBum i did not implemented setMyInteger in SecondViewController but I can call in FirstViewController...

Comment: In order to send `setMyInteger:` to `SecondViewController`, then `SecondViewController` must either implement this method or declare a property `myInteger` e.g. `@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger myInteger;`  Check the excellent answers below.

Comment: Mr @NSBum thanks for your reply! As I just said to XJones, your answer looks easy, clean and simple, but i'm still having trouble, i don't know where, I don't know why :( . Can you send me a working sample code with the answer of my question? By the way, i'm not using prepareForSegue method, ther is another viewController between both, e.g FirstViewController>SomeViewController>SecondViewController.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `myInteger` iVar is unused b/c of how the compiler generates iVars and synthesizes getters/setters automatically for properties.

The compiler helps you when you declare properties so you don't need to declare your own iVars or use @synthesize unless you want behavior other than the default.

The line `@property(nonatomic) NSInteger myInteger;` causes the compiler to generate the equivalent of the following in your implementation.

```
@synthesize myInteger = _myInteger;
```

Therefore, the iVar being modified by the default setter is `_myInteger`.

You can do one of the following in SecondViewController. I prefer solution #1 b/c it is cleaner, less code and takes advantage of automatic compiler behavior.

1. In SecondViewController.h remove the `myInteger` iVar and in SecondViewController.m change any references to the iVar to either `_myInteger` or `self.myInteger`

or

1. In SecondViewController.m, explicitly synthesize the property to use your iVar by adding `@synthesize myInteger;`

EDIT: ADDED SPECIFIC EXAMPLE

```
// SecondViewController.h
@interface SecondViewContoller : UIViewController
@property(nonatomic) NSInteger myInteger;
@end

// SecondViewControl.m
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    NSLog(@" the number is = %d", self.myInteger);
}

// FirstViewController.h
#import "SecondViewController"
//...

// FirstViewController.m
//
// rest of implementation
//
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath  *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath) {
        NSIndexPath *path = indexPath;
        NSInteger theInteger = path.row;
        NSLog(@"selected row = %d", theInteger);

        SecondViewController *second = [[SecondViewController alloc] init];
        second.myInteger = theInteger;
        // you need to present second somehow, viewDidLoad won't be called until then
        // example if using a navigationController
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:second animated:YES];
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you very much for your attention and your code looks very easy,simple and clean. But i'm still not getting the wright answer in my NSLog of viewDidLoad in SecondViewController. I would type the modified code I have from now, but I can't because of the number of characters :( . If it's possible, can you write a sample code for me with the stuff you're trying to explain, without prepareForSegue:sender method? There is another viewController between FirstViewController and SecondViewController e.g: First>someVC>Second

Thanks a lot, man!

Comment: I added to my answer. If this doesn't work than you have something else if your code. Simplify your code to this exact example and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Passing parameters onto the next one should be done in the `prepareForSegue:sender:` method assuming you're using Storyboards in Xcode 4.5.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    // Make sure your segue name in storyboard is the same as this line
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"YOUR_SEGUE_NAME_HERE"])
    {
       SecondViewController *second = (SecondViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
       second.selectedIndex = selectedIndex;
    }
}
```

Then in your didSelectRowAtIndexPath: method you can perform the segue:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"YOUR_SEGUE_NAME_HERE"];
```

And it should pass the parameter to your second view again assuming you have a property in the header file of your SecondViewController like such:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) int *selectedIndex;
```

**EDIT:**

In context with what you're trying to do you can easily make a private property in your FirstViewController at the top and store your selectedIndex from your didSelectRowAtIndexPath: there and pass it through in the prepareForSegue:

```
@interface FirstViewController() {
    int selectedIndex;
}
```

And

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath  *)indexPath {
    selectedIndex = indexPath.row
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but this code is not working fine. The first part (getting the index) is ok but, there is something with the prepareForSegue method that doesn't send selectedIndex properly, because when I type in SecondViewController.m

    -(void)viewDidLoad {
    NSLog(@"selected row is = %d");
    }

always return zero

Comment: Instead of dot syntax, try:  [second setSelectedIndex:selectedIndex];

Answer (score 0):

Hi i think you are missing to synthesize the myInteger Veriable modify your secondviewcontroller.m file

```
SecondViewControl.m

@synthesize myInteger;

-(void)viewDidLoad {
    NSLog(@" the number is = %d",myInteger); 
}
```

Hopefully this will help you :)

Comment: this answer is correct in that it will resolve the issue. see my answer for an explanation of why and an alternative by allowing compiler default behavior instead of overriding the ivar.